# Scaffolding in Rails while defining nullable fields and foreign keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scaffolding

I'm just figuring out my way around rails but I need a little help with the `rails generate scaffold` command.

Here's the command that I'd like to use

```
rails generate scaffold Expense user:??? name:string description:text
```

I'd like the `description` field to be nullable and the `users` field to be linked to another Model — in this case I'd like to create a foreign key to the Users. I'm using the `devise` authentication framework.

I've read that many RoR developers try and avoid the scaffolding method and opt for the manual approach instead but my web-app is quite simple and I've thought of going the scaffolding way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Scaffolding only generates the migration that you then run. Once the file is generated simply crack open the generated migration and adjust any of the values you need specific constraints on. By default columns are set to null unless you specify otherwise e.g.:

```
  create_table "slugs", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "sequence",                     :default => 1, :null => false
    t.string   "sluggable_type", :limit => 40
    t.string   "scope",          :limit => 40
    t.datetime "created_at"
  end
```

This is the code generated by the friendly_id plugin as you can see they have specified that the sequence column cannot be null while the other fields have other constraints.